# Update a "Category Blog" layout to Bootstrap 3

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla3.2

This is my first week working with Joomla! so please excuse me if I am approaching this the wrong way.

I have created my own template using bootstrap 3 (very simple, nothing crazy). I removed the Bootstrap 2 framework in my index.php. I have completed a static homepage and I am trying not to get the Blog section working. What I want is to be able to post articles and have the page constantly show the most up to date articles.

To do this, I added a menu item, named it "Blog", and choose a Menu Item Type of "Category Blog." (**Question: is "Category Blog" the correct Menu Item Type?**)

Since Joomla still uses Bootstrap 2, the grid system nor the pagination does not work. I would like to override the current default.php layout to include Bootstrap 3 elements. 
**Would I create an override for:**

```
../com_content/category/default.php
```

Or do I have to create and override for each module such as the pagination and the layout.

**I have read [This Guide](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core) on how to do override but I am unsure what files I need to edit exactly.**

Answer (score 2):

Alright guys I figured it out.

To know which file to update and over write you have to go to 
Administrator page -> Menus -> *Your Menu* -> link

For example mine said:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=8
```

So I had to edit blog.php, within category, that was within com_content

If you follow [this guide](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides) it will tell you how to create an override in 3.2

I found all the locations where the php said "span" and replaced it with bootstrap 3 grid system (ex: col-lg-)